# Unexpected result from EDNS Client Subnet on Google Public DNS

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm been trying to run a test around EDNS. Simply to check if the IPs returned are closest when using the EDNS extension.

However, if I query using an IP from China, I get returned an IP with a location of the US. As shown below.

Any thoughts?

```
curl -s http://ip-api.com/json/59.155.255.200  | jq
{
  "as": "",
  "city": "Xinzhuang (Minhang Qu)",
  "country": "China",
  "countryCode": "CN",
  "isp": "zhuyuan road, Shanghai, China",
  "lat": 31.0704,
  "lon": 121.518,
  "org": "zhuyuan road, Shanghai, China",
  "query": "59.155.255.200",
  "region": "",
  "regionName": "Shanghai",
  "status": "success",
  "timezone": "Asia/Shanghai",
  "zip": ""
}

./bin/dig/dig @8.8.8.8 www.google.com +client=59.155.255.200 +short
216.58.208.164

curl -s http://ip-api.com/json/216.58.208.164  | jq
{
  "as": "AS15169 Google LLC",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "country": "United States",
  "countryCode": "US",
  "isp": "Google",
  "lat": 37.4192,
  "lon": -122.0574,
  "org": "Google",
  "query": "216.58.208.164",
  "region": "CA",
  "regionName": "California",
  "status": "success",
  "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "zip": "94043"
}
```

Or if there is a better way to test the IP location returned from testing EDNS please let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: All of Google's IP addresses are registered to their Mountain View, California location, regardless of where the machines answering them are. Some are even anycast addresses and answered at multiple locations around the world. This is the wrong way to find out if an IP address is "closest" to you.

Comment: Thanks, if you have a better way to test / confirm ip location from a EDNS test please let me know. Quest updated

Comment: @MichaelHampton It turns out that `ip-api.com` has other data than just what you can find using `whois`. If I follow the steps in the question but fix the mistake made along the way, I get an IP address which says Mountain View in the whois data but Japan in the data from `ip-api.com`. Btw. Google does have some IP addresses listed in whois as other locations than Mountain View, but that's not really relevant to this question anyway.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The real issue in this question is confusion on Recursive vs Authoritative DNS servers. I have explained that in [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/938825/214507) and shown how when that mistake is corrected `59.155.255.200` ends up being served by a location listed as `Japan`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDNS is a way to support many different extensions of the DNS protocol. Your question is specifically about the Client Subnet option, which is just one of the many things EDNS can be used for.

The Client Subnet option is intended for recursive DNS servers to communicate the client IP address to authoritative DNS servers such that the authoritative DNS servers can respond with IP addresses that have a lower roundtrip time to the client.

Google operate both recursive DNS servers and authoritative DNS servers. The recursive DNS servers operated by Google are known by the name Google Public DNS.

Google supports the Client Subnet option on both Google Public DNS and on authoritative servers. So when a client sends a query for `www.google.com` to Google Public DNS the request sent from Google Public DNS to Google's authoritative DNS servers will contain a Client Subnet option with the IP address of the client (possibly truncated).

What you did was to send the Client Subnet option to Google Public DNS. That does not make sense because that's a request from client to recursive DNS, which is not what the Client Subnet option is for. The option is for communication from recursive DNS to authoritative DNS.

Had you instead sent that request to one of Google's authoritative DNS servers, you would have gotten a different result as in this example:

```
$ dig +short +norecurse www.google.com @ns3.google.com
216.58.206.68
$ dig +short +norecurse +subnet=59.155.255.200 www.google.com @ns3.google.com
172.217.25.196
```

Notice that when querying the authoritative servers the option does make a difference. (Notice that when the option was introduced it was named `+client` for a brief period before being renamed to `+subnet`)

If we look up that IP address in `ip-api.com` we see that it is listed as Japan, which I guess is closer to what you were expecting to see.

```
$ curl http://ip-api.com/json/172.217.161.68
{"as":"AS15169 Google LLC","city":"Chiyoda","country":"Japan","countryCode":"JP","isp":"Google","lat":35.694,"lon":139.754,"org":"Google","query":"172.217.161.68","region":"","regionName":"Tokyo","status":"success","timezone":"Asia/Tokyo","zip":"100-0001"}
```

We can thus deduce that `ip-api.com` must have other data sources than just `whois` since when I use `whois 172.217.161.68` I get this:

```
OrgName:        Google LLC
OrgId:          GOGL
Address:        1600 Amphitheatre Parkway
City:           Mountain View
StateProv:      CA
PostalCode:     94043
Country:        US
```

Comment: An amazing answer, *thank you* for taking the time to explain.